# Deploying Java Spring Boot Application to Azure Web App Linux

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, war, azure-web-app-service

I struggle since 3 days with deprecated tutorials and not even working Microsoft docs.

After the Microsoft Docs did not really help me I tried to do the following:

Using the IntelliJ CE Plugin for Azure I try to deploy [this](https://github.com/bbenz/spring-boot-todo) demo
to Azure App Service.

From the plugin I chose "Run on Web App", which succeeds as:

```
Stopping Web App...
Getting Deployment Credential...
Connecting to FTP server...
Removing from FTP server: /site/wwwroot/webapps/TodoDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Uploading artifact to: /site/wwwroot/webapps/TodoDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ...
Uploading successfully...
Logging out of FTP server...
Starting Web App...
Deploy successfully!
URL: https://**********.azurewebsites.net/TodoDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Then, clicking the link "URL" I end up at:
[image: Whitelabel Error Page]

What step am I missing?

Here some more info about the environment:

[image: Application Settings]

I did not change any other setting from the out-of-the-box Web App.

PS: If I deploy the same WAR to a VM on Azure, everything works fine. Happy to provide more info if necessary.

Comment: Could you change "Stack" in App Service configuration from "Java SE (JRE8)" to "Tomcat 8.5 (JRE)" and check if it works then?

Comment: I managed to get it to work in the meantime but there is many grey zones which I am already working on with a MS employee to update their docs. I will officially answer my question once I have a nice doc. 
In the meantime: https://gravity-global.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GPUB/pages/572325889/gravity.azure.run
This link will stop working once I wrote a nice doc.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I managed to get it to run and wrote a Medium story about my struggles and learning.

https://medium.com/@dmnkmyr/java-web-apps-on-azure-the-hunt-for-up-to-date-documentation-730e5cbabd45

Also during that time MS seems to have worked on it and there is docs now. I put them here and in Medium.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/maven/docs/web-app-samples?view=azure-java-stable

Good look everyone